# WP8 Loaded event not always called

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I have a LongListSelector using binding, dataTemplate, etc.
In the dataTemplate there is one element where I set a **Loaded** event to be fired so I can then populate programatically the content of this element.
When the first time I do a App.ItemsViewModel.add(...) the **Loaded** event is fired, but when I then do a App.ItemsViewModel.Remove(0), the first element is removed, ok, but when I then do a App.ItemsViewModel.add(...) the new item is added to the list, but the **Loaded** event is not called anymore, as the object would be cached or something like that. How can I solve this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `LongListSelector` uses data virtualization and recycling. Your datatemplate is reused to display the next items, and that's why the `Loaded` event isn't always raised. Either disable data virtualization on the list (probably not a good idea) or rethink your architecture. Depending on exactly what you're doing, there's probably an alternative way or another event you can use, but we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Can you please provide some xaml and code?

Comment: I think the first comment is already the right answer.